# Function for inputting three integers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am having trouble with my function getThreeIntegers. How do I properly write it with pointers and get it to return result? When I run it everything displays as 0. I am struggling with writing the proper format.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define flush fflush(stdin)

//Prototype Functions Here
void displayAverage(int n1, int n2, int n3);
void displayLowest(int n1, int n2, int n3);
void displayProduct(int n1, int n2, int n3);
void displaySum(int n1, int n2, int n3);
void getMenu();
char getUserChoice();
int getThreeIntegers(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3);

main() {
        //Declare Variables Here
        char choice = ' '; //used by menu
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;

        do{
        choice = getUserChoice();
        switch(choice) {
            case 'A':
                getThreeIntegers(&num1, &num2, &num3);
                pause;
                break;
            case 'B':
                displaySum(num1, num2, num3);
                pause;
                break;
            case 'C':
                displayProduct(num1, num2, num3);
                pause; 
                break;
            case 'D': 
                displayAverage(num1, num2, num3);
                pause;
                break;
            case 'E':
                displayLowest(num1, num2, num3);
                pause;
                break;
            case 'F':
                printf("Goodbye! \n\n");
                pause;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Selection...\n\n");
                pause;
                break;
        } // end switch
    }while(choice != 'F');
} // end main

void displayAverage(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    float average = 0.0;
    int sum = num1 + num2 + num3; 
    average = sum/3; 

        printf("The average of the integers is: %.2lf\n", average);

} //end displayAverage

void displayLowest(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int lowest;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; 

    if(a < b && a < c)
            lowest = a;
    printf("The lowest integer is: %i\n", a);
} // end displayLowest

void displayProduct(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int product;
    product = num1*num2*num3;
    printf("The product of the integers is: %i\n", product);
} // end displayProduct

void displaySum(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int sum;
    sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
    printf("The sum of the integers is: %i\n", sum);

} // end displaySum

void getMenu() { //displays menu onto output
    cls;
    printf("\t MAIN MENU\n");
    printf("*************************\n\n");
    printf("A. Enter three integers.\n");
    printf("B. Display the sum.\n");
    printf("C. Display the product.\n");
    printf("D. Display the average. \n");
    printf("E. Display the lowest number. \n");
    printf("F. Quit. \n\n");
    printf("*************************\n");
    printf("Enter user choice: "); 
    return; 
} // getMenu

char getUserChoice(){
   char result;
   getMenu(); //call to function
   scanf("%c", &result); //user enters their choice
   result = toupper(result); //converts char to capital
   flush;
   return result;
} // end getChoice

int getThreeIntegers(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3) {
    printf("Enter first integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &n1);
    printf("Enter second integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &n2);
    printf("Enter third integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &n3);
    flush;
    return n1, n2, n3; 
} //end getThreeIntegers
```

Comment: `scanf("%i", &n1);` --> `scanf("%i",  n1);`. ditto.  also `displayLowest` is wrong.

Comment: `return n1, n2, n3; ` meant `return n3;` also Type is different.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I write the function for displayLowest?

Comment: you need compare three things: `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`. I wouldn't want to give away the exact code to do it. If you had 3, 4, and 5. You'd compare the first two numbers, and compare the smallest of those with the 3rd number to get the smallest.

Comment: such as MIN(MIN(num1, num2), num3)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ampersand `&` before `n1, n2, n3`.

`scanf` wants the address of the memory where it should write the value from user input. Here, the address is `n1`, etc. If you had just `int n1`, then you'd want to get the address of `n1`, so you'd need to use `&`. However, since you have `int * n1`, `n1` already has the address of where the integer needs to be stored. So, no need to use `&`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the prototype of the function by changing the return value to `void` instead of `int` because the values are passed by their address so any change made will affect them permanently

```
void  getThreeIntegers(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3);
```

now you need to make the changes inside the block of the function like below

```
void  getThreeIntegers(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3) { // change the return value to void 
    printf("Enter first integer: ");
    //you need to pass the address of the variable in scanf()
    //and as n1 hold the address you pass like it is 
    // delete the & sign from every variable in `scanf()`
    scanf("%i", n1);
    printf("Enter second integer: ");
    scanf("%i", n2);
    printf("Enter third integer: ");
    scanf("%i", n3);
    //flush;           // delete this line
    //return n1, n2, n3; // no need for return as the variable are passed by reference 
     // 
} //end getThreeIntegers
```

Now if you define for instance 3 integers `a`,`b`,`c`

```
int a=0,b=0,c=0;
```

the call of the function will be at that time:

```
getThreeIntegers(&a,&b,&c);
```

Concerning the function called `displayLowest` you want to get the lowest variable from the three integers so the idea is to compare two integers after that you need to compare the lowest between them to the third so here is how you can write it in one line using the ternary operator `?:`

```
void displayLowest(int num1, int num2, int num3) {

     printf("The lowest integer is: %i\n", (num1 < num2 ? num1 : num2) < num3 ? (num1 < num2 ? num1 : num2) : num3);

} // end displayLowest
```

For the function `displayProduc()` I think it will be a little bit safer if you define the variable `product` with `long long int` type especially as it holds the product of 3 integers of type `int` ! In this way you will **reduce** the probability of going beyond the limits !

Don't forget of course the `printf()` for the print (note the `%lli`)

```
printf("The product of the integers is: %lli\n", product);
```

and let me finish this answer with a note that must be kept in mind

### Never use flush(stdin) because this will lead your program to undefined behavior

Hope it helps !